# Codesign error while archiving IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, code-signing

I am new to IOS. I have developed an IOS application now i want to publish this application on iTunes. I have created Certificate, App ID and then Provisional profile. I have succesfully added this in “Code Signing” section of "Build Setting”. Now, while Archiving the project i am getting a following error.

> error: Couldn't codesign /Users/dx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-dgsqnqppikhtqeezizlbydrpxfiz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/xxxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1*

Please help me out of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any more information in the error output?

Comment: Quit xcode and open it again clean the project and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-generate your provisioning profile from Apple Developer Center. As far as I know they add something new to profiles and that causes the problem.

Solution

In keychain access, -> Show Expired Certificates, then in your login keychain click on expired certificate and delete it. I also had the same expired certificate in my System keychain, so I deleted it from there too.

-> After deleting the expired cert from the login and System keychains,download certificate from below link and open with keychain.

Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and add it to Keychain access > certificates (which expires on 2023)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply, my problem was with keychain. I had not added certificate in it. This problem is solved but now when i am trying to upload it to APP STORE. I am getting an error "Missing  iOS Distribution signing identity for my user" . When i checked my certificate in keychain it also giving error "This Certificate has an invalid issuer".  I have tried many solutions from stack overflow like removing expired certificates from "Login keychain" but still getting the same error. Could you please help me out of this.Thanks in advance.